# How to test and mocking a function Nodejs with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, callback, mocking, jestjs

I want to test a function. This function also need other function, but this other function will be mocked with jest.

Here is my function

```
translate(args, cb) {
    const transid = args.transid;
    const language = args.language;
    const defaultValue = args.defaultValue || '';

    if (transid === null || transid === '') {
      return cb(new Error('Error. Need TransiD'));
    }
    if (language === null || language === '') {
      return cb(new Error('Error. Need language'));
    }

    return this.translation(transid, language, defaultValue)
      .then((res) => {
        return cb(null, res);
      });
  }
```

That function need function 'translation'. in testing process, i will mocking it.

Here is my function for testing

```
describe('Translator', () => {
  describe('translate', () => {

    it('Should return translated value', (done) => {
      const args = {
        transid: 1,
        language: 'EN',
        defaultValue: 'defaultValue',
      }
      const cb = jest.fn((err, res) => {

      });
      translator.translation = jest.fn((transid, language, defaultValue) => {
        // done();
      })

      translator.translate(args, cb);
      done();
    });
  })
})
```

I am still confusing how to test that function using Jest and also mocking the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I can see:

- You can avoid using Jest’s `done` function by returning the Promise chain, which Jest will use to determine when a test is complete.
- You don't need to mock the implementation of the functions, just their return values. You might want to create an additional test that does mock the implementation behavior, but its good to start with just controlling their output.

Here's how the test might look:

```
describe('Translator', () => {
  describe('translate', () => {
    it('Should return translated value', () => {
      const args = {
        transid: 1,
        language: 'EN',
        defaultValue: 'defaultValue',
      }

      const cb = jest.fn();

      const res = {};

      translator.translation = jest.fn()
        .mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(res));

      return translator.translate(args, cb)
        .then(() => {
          expect(translator.translation).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(translator.translation)
            .toHaveBeenCalledWith(1, 'EN', 'defaultValue');

          expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
          expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null, res);
        });
    });
  })
})
```